# Xcode Debugging - Multiple Executables

Tags: xcode, debugging, executable

I have multiple native targets defined in my Xcode 3.2.5 project. For example, IT's and UT's. I have chosen utProjectExecutable as my active executable and utProjectTarget as my active target. Still, when I hit Run->Debug it runs the IT's executable instead of UT's.

Note: I am running it in Debug mode.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Quit Xcode, delete `your_project.xcodeproj/your_username.*`, restart Xcode. NB: do **not** delete `your_project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had to delete all other files except your_project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj in your_project.xcodeproj/. Then I again added my utExecutable to the list of executables. It works now!

Comment: That's good - I'll move my comment and make it an answer then, as it may be useful to someone else in the future...

Answer (score 1):

- Quit Xcode
- Delete `your_project.xcodeproj/your_username.*`
- Restart Xcode.

  NB: do **not** delete `your_project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` !